# Function for generating queries to restore constraints after drop based on table with constraint information

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I have to drop all constraints in my Postgres database to update datatypes used by PKs and FKs. Before that I want to make sure that I can rebuild those constraints after the update. At first I execute the following code to get a table with three columns **table_from**, **conname** and **pg_get_constraintdef**, containing all constraint information.

```
select conrelid::regclass AS table_from, conname, pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid)
from   pg_constraint c
join   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.connamespace
where  contype in ('f', 'p','c','u') order by contype
```

**table_from** contains the table name, e.g. `foo`. **conname** the name of the constraint, e.g. `fk_foo_2_bar` and **pg_get_constraintdef** contains the constraint definition, e.g.
`FOREIGN KEY (foo_id) REFERENCES bar(bar_id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`

How can I generate all the queries for creating my constraints? I don't want to do it by hand, because there are 1000+ constraints active.

Comment: Surely I must be missing something, but could you not use this query to obtain the queries you want through simple string concatenation? You have the name of the table, the name of the constraint and its definition, is there something else that's missing?

Comment: To clarify, I'm thinking of something along the line of `select 'alter table ' || conrelid::regclass || ' add constraint ' || conname || etc. etc.`, or whatever the syntax is, leaving the rest of your query as it is.

Comment: Ok, haven't noticed that I already have half of the work done, I'll give it a try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the work was actually done already...

```
select 'alter table ' || conrelid::regclass || ' add constraint ' || conname || ' ' || pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid)
from   pg_constraint c
join   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.connamespace
where  contype in ('f', 'p','c','u') order by contype
```